# Convert Selection query to update query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select rank in sql, the selection query working fine how to convert this selection into update and update the columns as well.

```
SET @i=0  ;

SELECT sno, email, points, @i:=@i+1 AS rank FROM user ORDER BY points DESC
```

how to update this selection in table as well

Got the query from  [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13703/get-the-rank-of-a-user-in-a-score-table)

Comment: Update what table , update what columns(?). You could improve this question by providing sample data and expected outcome as text in the question.

Comment: Want to update rank

Comment: Hello, it would be easier to help you if you provide the table data !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @i=0; 
UPDATE user SET rank= @i:= (@i+1) ORDER BY points DESC;
```

Comment: Not Working, it makes every column empty

Comment: sorry i have changed variable now check again

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `sno` is the primary key of your table, you want :

```
SET @i=0  ;
UPDATE user
JOIN (
    SELECT sno, email, points, @i:=@i+1 AS rank
    FROM user 
    ORDER BY points DESC
) AS ranks ON ranks.sno = user.sno 
SET user.rank = ranks.rank
```

Comment: @Nipun your table name

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order USING(sno) Getting this error

Comment: @Nipun : mm I think `order` is a reserverd word, I changed the query a little, please check again